# Repeating the same word in relative clause and independent clause

Tags: conjunctions, relative-clauses

Do you think if the following sentence grammatically okay  or should we rewrite because the word gasoline are placed closely?

> Automobile manufacturers are producing smaller cars, which use less
>   gasoline,  since gasoline  is becoming expensive .

Comment: "Of all the books of the Occident which have come down to us, the most ancient is Homer; it is there that one finds... the idea of that destiny which is master of *the gods, as the gods* are masters of the world." Voltaire.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise strongly that you rewrite the sentence. Writing that is engaging uses a wide variety of sentence structures and a rich, varied vocabulary. What makes writing tedious is repetition. It becomes a chore to wade through repetition.

One possible fix:

> Because gas is becoming expensive, automobile manufacturers are
>   producing smaller cars, which use less of it.

This may not be the best solution--you have to look at the larger context. The fact is, most weaker writers don't necessarily repeat words in the same sentence, but they do repeat them within a paragraph, or they use something like "in order to" in every paragraph, or the begin two or three paragraphs with the same word, or with identically constructed sentences (using a *not only ... but also* construction three times on one page).

And who wants to read something like that? Variety is the spice of life they say--it works for writing too. Keep it lively, not stagnant.

In short, using repetition, except for dramatic effect, or poetic expression, is not a writer's best strategy.